# Need to know how to sum totals in a sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query, but I need to be able to give a "**total number" of each of the columns listed.**

Can someone please help?

Here is my sql:

```
select PartnerAbbrev,
    count(TrafficPreApplications.Id) as Hits,
    SUM(Case WHEN TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_1,
    SUM(Case WHEN  TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_2,
    SUM(Case WHEN TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_3,
    SUM(Case WHEN TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_4,
    SUM(Case WHEN  TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_5,
    SUM(Case WHEN TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_6,
    SUM(Case WHEN  TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_7,
    SUM(Case WHEN  TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_9,
    SUM(Case WHEN  TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 999 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_999,
    SUM(Case WHen  TrafficHitId is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Today_PreApp
from TrafficPreApplications full join TrafficHits on TrafficPreApplications.TrafficHitId = traffichits.Id
 join TrafficPartners on TrafficPartners.Id = TrafficHits.TrafficPartnerId
 join Partners on Partners.Id = TrafficPartners.PartnerId
 group by PartnerAbbrev
```

Comment: Are you asking for an additional row at the bottom with the grand totals for each column?

Answer (score 2):

you dont need that full join, you remove any rows from `TrafficHits` without `TrafficPreApplications` anyway.

```
select Partners.Id,
       PartnerAbbrev,
       count(TrafficPreApplications.Id) as Hits,
       SUM(Case WHEN TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_1,
       ... 
from TrafficPreApplications 
right join TrafficHits on TrafficPreApplications.TrafficHitId = traffichits.Id
join TrafficPartners on TrafficPartners.Id = TrafficHits.TrafficPartnerId
join Partners on Partners.Id = TrafficPartners.PartnerId
group by Partners.Id, PartnerAbbrev
union all
    select max(Partners.Id)+1,
       'total',
       count(TrafficPreApplications.Id) as Hits,
       SUM(Case WHEN TrafficPreApplications.laststep = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hit1_1,
       ... 
from TrafficPreApplications 
right join TrafficHits on TrafficPreApplications.TrafficHitId = traffichits.Id
join TrafficPartners on TrafficPartners.Id = TrafficHits.TrafficPartnerId
join Partners on Partners.Id = TrafficPartners.PartnerId
order by 1,2
```